# Rounding to .25 or .5

Tags: math, integer, rounding, calculator

Anyone know how to round to a .5 or .25 ? My dosage calculator
(https://www.jwm.guide/edible-dosage-calculator) can only round to nearest integer and for cooking purposes that isn't precise enough, but currently it is too precise without rounding.

i'm using calconic, which does not have this natively. I know I can multiply x10, round, and then / 10 but that still only gets me to within .1 instead of .25 or .5

Any formulas I can use for this?

Comment: `I know I can multiply x10, round, and then / 10 but that still only gets me to within .1 instead of .25 or .5` so use 2 or 4 instead of 10.

Comment: @tkausl - indeed! Thank you, sometimes it's hard to see something so simple when too deep in the problem. Much appreciated.